# ASP.NET Webform OnClick event not firing properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a Default page (initial landing page) with a bunch of asp controls and everything works great.  I also have an Admin page with one asp button control (I simplified for the post).  Both are wrapped in form element on a Site.Master page.  The button click event does not fire on my Admin page.  Here is my button event and page code/code behind:

Page code

```
<%@ Page Title="Admin1" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Admin1.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="HPRMWebClientReporting.Admin1" %>         

 <asp:Content runat="server" ID="AdminContent" 
    ContentPlaceHolderID="AdminContent">
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonGo" runat="server" Text="Button" Width="111px" 
    OnClick="ButtonGo_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class Admin1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        }
    }

    protected void ButtonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Context.Items["Msg"] = "It worked!!!.";
        Server.Transfer("MessagePage.aspx");
    }
}
```

Here is what happens:

1. Goes through Page_Load of Default page
2. Goes through Page_Load of Site.Master page
3. Refreshes my site and shows the Default page

At no point does it go my click event or Page_Load of my Admin page when the button is clicked?  The button click should be taking it to the MessagePage page.

This is driving me crazy.  I did try turning Causes Validation to false on the button with no luck.  Any ideas?

Note: Also, maybe this will help someone determine what I'm doing wrong.  I changed the Page Code so it does not use the MasterPageFile Site.Master and I just wrapped the button in its own form element and it worked fine but I don't want it to work that way as I want to use the Master page.

Comment: It appears that you should be using a MasterPage for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that worked although I am not entirely sure why without further research.  In my Site.Master page and in the form element I mentioned in the post I pulled out the **action="/"** and now my controls work on Admin page as I expected them too.

```
 <form id="Form1" action="/" method="post" runat="server">     
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HomeContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContactContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="AboutContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="AdminContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

Comment: That should be fine, my forms on my master pages look like this:
<form runat="server">

Comment: Thanks for confirming the form element.  I was struggling with this for a few days not even thinking it could be something in the Master.